# Check if line contains specific characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

How to check if a string contains only paranthesis, comma, number, and any combination of "urld" separated with a string? It should always be in the below form:

```
(0,3),u,r,u,l,u #True

(0,3),u,r,u,l,u #True

(0,3),u,r,u,l u #False because of space b/w l and u
```

I tried something like this but seems like I am off:

```
if !misc_text.match(/^(\d+,\d+\)(,[udlr])+)/)
```

Comment: So close! You just need to escape the parentheses.

Comment: I don't think you intended the first two examples to be identical.  Please add `(0,3),u,r,u,lu` to your examples.  I assume it is `false` because there is no intervening character other than `[urld]` between the last two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples suggest that not all of the letters 'u', 'r', 'l', 'd' need be present.  I have assumed that the string may contain any number of each of these four letters (in addition to the other permitted characters).  I have also assumed that 'any combination of "urld" separated with a string' means that each pair of these four characters must be separated by one or more of the other permitted characters.  This is one way to accomplish that:

```
def check_it(s)
  (s.chars.chunk {|c| c =~ /[urld]/}.to_a.size == s.count('urld') &&
    s =~ /^[(),\durld]*$/) ? true : false
end

check_it('(0,3),u,r,u,l,u') #=> true
check_it('(0,3),u,r,u,l u') #=> false
check_it('(0,3),u,r,u,lu')  #=> false
```

Suppose

```
s = '(0,3),u,r,u,lu'
```

Then

```
a = s.chars.chunk {|c| c =~ /[urld]/}.to_a
  #=> [[0, ["u"]], [0, ["r"]], [0, ["u"]], [0, ["l", "u"]]]

a.size #=> 4

s.count('urld') #=> 5
```

As `a.size < s.count('urld')`, `count_it()` returns `false`

If instead:

```
s = '(0,3),u,r,u,l u'
```

then

```
s.chars.chunk {|c| c =~ /[urld]/}.to_a.size
  #=> a = [[0, ["u"]], [0, ["r"]], [0, ["u"]], [0, ["l"]], [0, ["u"]]]
  #   a.size => 5
  #   5 == s.count('urld') => true
```

but

```
s =~ /^[(),\durld]*$/ #=> nil
```

so `check_it() => false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me and explanation was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need this regex: `/^(\(\d+,\d+\)(,[udlr])+)$/`.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do as follows, mixing the [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp), and [array](/questions/tagged/array) operations:

```
class String
   def catch str
      str.split('').all? {|l| /,#{l}(,|\b)/ =~ self }
   end
end
```

so:

```
"(0,3),u,r,u,l,d".catch('ulrd') # => true

"(0,3),u,r,u,l d".catch('ulrd') # => false
```

Comment: `"(0,3),u,r,u,l".catch 'ulrd' #=> false`.  Shouldn't this be true?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess should not, because `d` isn't present in string

Comment: @CarySwoveland that rule doesn't make sense then if `l u` has a space, i.e. didn't splitted with `,`

Comment: @CarySwoveland do you think that `lu` returns true? We'll ask the author =)

Comment: @CarySwoveland exactly, where is the difference between `lu`, `l u`? I don't see, because as you said in both cases: `because no intervening '(', ')'`